# Flex box column row issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In having an issue in Internet explorer where it does not render flex box elements correctly in conjunction to rows.

Columns seem to work fine in both browsers but...

IE 11 seems to be shrinking the rows for no reason? meaning I can fix it by applying flex: 1 0 auto(prevent shrinking) to rows and flex:1 to columns but is not constant code.

Is there a fix to it in IE or am I doing something wrong as Chrome renders it correctly this is my current fix and seems like a hack to me.

Chrome

[image]

IE:

[image]

```html
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    div.form {
      display: block;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    div.container-row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: white;
    }
    div.container-col {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      background-color: white;
    }
    div.field {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: purple;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    div.value {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    input[type=text] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="form">
    <div class="container-row">
      <div class="field">hiiiiiiiidddsssssssdddddddd</div>
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-row">
      <div class="field">hiiiiiiiidddsssssssdddddddd</div>
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-col">
      <div class="field">hiiiiiiiidddsssssssdddddddd</div>
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-col">
      <div class="field">hiiiiiiiidddsssssssdddddddd</div>
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e2jwc371/3/

Cheers for the help ;)

Comment: according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)  ie10 partially supports flexboxes with  `-ms-` prefix - test adding it on ie11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `flex: 1;`, you're not only setting `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`. You're also setting `flex-basis` (relative sizing between the elements) to **0%**. That's probably what's confusing IE.

Change the `flex` properties to use auto-sizing (`flex: 1 auto;`), and it works correctly in IE too:

```
...
div.field {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 auto;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.value {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 auto;
  background-color: pink;
}
...
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e2jwc371/4/